# Confused about a particular example of rational canonical form.... please help me find my error.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-verification

The minimal polynomial of the matrix $A = (\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix})$ is $x^2 + 1$. (At least, I think so - how can one be sure about this?) If we think of this matrix as being in $M_n(R)$, then the elementary factors are just $x^2 + 1$, so it is already in rational canonical form. However, if we think of this matrix as being in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, then the elementary factors are $(x - i)$ and $(x + i)$. This gives rational canonical form $(\begin{smallmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{smallmatrix})$.

I just read an exercise that says that, for a matrix $A \in M_n(F)$, $F$ a field, the entries in the rational canonical form are in the smallest subfield containing the entries of $A$. For $F = \mathbb{C}$ and $A = (\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix})$ as above, this smallest subfield is $Q$, and yet my computation above yields a rational canonical form $(\begin{smallmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{smallmatrix})$.

I would appreciate it very much if someone pointed out a contradiction in my thinking. (Also, how can one be sure that they have found the minimal polynomial?)

(The exercise is number 3 in chapter 7 in Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra: "Let A be a square matrix over a field F. Let K be the smallest subfield of F containing the entries of A. Prove that any rational canonical form for A has coefficients in the field K.")

Comment: Clearly $A$ doesn't satisfy any linear polynomial, so the polynomial you found must be of lowest possible degree, and it's evidently monic, hence it's minimal.

Comment: @seaturtles Ah, of course. Thanks - though it doesn't seem that that method will generalize to higher order polynomials. Do you know of any good tricks for knowing when one has found the minimal polynomial?

Comment: The minimal polynomial has all of the same zeros as the characteristic polynomial. So if you've found a polynomial which is minimal subject to both having all of the same roots as the characteristic polynomial and having coefficients in the base field, then you know you've found the minimal polynomial. This applies in particular when forming the product of linear factors, precisely one for each eigenvalue, yields a polynomial whose coefficients are in the base field.

Comment: Huh? The minimal polynomial for $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is $p(t)=t^2$, not $p(t)=t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wrong about the elementary factors over $\Bbb C$. Remember that you must have successive divisibility.

Comment: I was confused about the difference between "invariant factors" (= elementary factors?) and elementary divisors. Are the invariant factors indeed "invariant" of the base field? If so, then the exercise I mentioned follows since I could have computed the invariant factors in $K$.

Comment: What I am currently thinking  - suppose that $k[X] \subseteq F[X]$, with $k \subseteq F$ a field extension so that $F$ is finitely generated over $k$, and suppose that $V$ a finite dimensional $F$-vector space. Then $V \cong \oplus \frac{F[x]}{(f_i(x))}$ as $F[x]$ modules, so also as $k[x]$ modules. Thus, $\oplus \frac{F[x]}{(f_i(x))} \cong \oplus \frac{k[x]}{(g_i(x))}$ as $k[x]$ modules, since both are $k[x]$ isomorphic to $V$. But it seems that there will be more copies of cyclic $k[t]$ modules here, meaning more invariant factors, which flies in the face of the uniqueness I want...

Comment: ...Nevermind. I worked through the relevant sections in Dummit and Foote and this makes sense now. Essentially, a matrix in rational canonical form implies a specific cyclic decomposition of the space, along with some invariant factors. The uniqueness theorems for such decompositions then shows that these invariant factors must coincide, so any two similar matrices in rational canonical form must be the same - regardless of the field.

Comment: (Though isn't it necessary that $F$ be finitely generated over $k$ in order for the classification of f.g. torsion modules to apply? And why is it that a $k$-linear transformation would remain an $F$ linear transformation? There are some things that are still confusing me, but it is late...)

Comment: No, you're viewing $F^n$ as an $F[t]$-module or $k^n$ as a $k[t]$-module, the module structure being given by $A$ in either case.

Comment: Yeah, those questions did clear up upon waking up this morning - $A$ defines a new linear transformation for each $k^n$ or $F^n$. I think I understand this now. Thanks for your help. :-)